# What do I need to prepare if I want to dispute action taken against me by my company?

Tags: salary

I recently took a day off. I followed company procedure, applied well in-advance, was given approval, and the day off was listed in the company schedule.

After coming back from the day off, the boss refused to grant the day off and docked me a day's pay as a result.

I want to leave my option to dispute this open, and want to make sure that I prepare documentation to help prove my claim now rather than later in case it becomes unavailable.

What documentation (i.e. e-mails, hard copies of schedules, etc.) should I prepare to show that I had gained approval for this day off?

Comment: the best advice I can give at this point is to document and take the documentation off-site. YOu ned the approvals for teh leave and any emails about the issue. You need the dates and time and a summary of the discussion about whether to fire people. You are likely being positioned to be released, so make sure everything you might possibily need to have a case is taken out of the office ASAP. Then contact your state Department of Labor and see if they can offer advice.

Comment: Hey user, and welcome to [workplace.se]. Although your question was put on hold, I think it has the core of a good question so I am going to make a significant [edit] to it to try to refocus it and get it reopened so you can get an answer. If you think my edit misses the point or won't be helpful, feel free to make an [edit] of your own to improve it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I am documenting all of this right away and I will have it in my briefcase. I plan on contacting Dept Of Labor if and when I get fired. It hasn't happened and thus my question I posed here. What should I do, if anything, while working here? If I file something or fight for what I am entitled to I will for sure be let go, but if I don't say something I am just accepting this as ok to do to me, and/or others. I'm stuck on what to do.

Comment: @user13114 - No, not in your briefcase.  Get it OFF SITE.  You may notice a little sign on your way in that says "All persons and their belongings are subject to search."  Get copies out of the office immediately.  Don't carry them with you, get them out of there!

Answer (score 1):

In your question,

> I followed company procedure, applied well in-advance, **was given approval**, and the day off was listed in the company schedule.

If the approval was in verbal, I don't think you will win (**Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer**). If the approval was in writing, say an e-mail, you need to present it to the HR to appeal for the manager's action.

If the approval in the e-mail was **not clearly written**, you may not win, depending on what your manager wrote in that e-mail. For example, something like, *I will let you know my decision before that day*, and you never got his confirmation, you probably won't win.

Company schedule is supplemental to the manager's approval, but I think the manager has the power to override it, say if his department had emergency work to do.

Answer (score 1):

### Executive Summary

1. Show your rights
2. Show the rules regarding those rights
3. Show that you followed the rules

### Rights

Make sure that you have something that shows you have paid leave under your contract, and preferably that you had leave left at the time of the request.

If you get a payslip each month saying how many days of paid leave you have accrued, get the slip for that month. If your contract explains you have X days of paid leave a year, make a copy.

### Rules

Make sure that you have something that explains the rules to getting approval for leave.

If that is written in your contract, make a copy. If it is written in an employee handbook, get a copy. If it is written in some unofficial memo sent around to employees, get a copy. If it was by e-mail, print it out. If it was communicated verbally, get copies of all your other leave requests to show that you were following the same procedure.

### Approval

Make sure that you have something to show that you followed the rules to get approval.

If you have the rules written down, try to get information for each step of the process to show that you followed it. If you have e-mails acknowledging your request was approved (especially if all your previous leave requests had the same e-mail and were not disputed by the company), then keep those too. If you had to send an initial e-mail to make the request, keep that. If you have a copy of the calendar showing your leave on it, keep that.

> Disclaimer: I am not a lawyer. Some of these documents may contains sensitive or proprietary information that could be protected by an agreement you've signed with the company and you may be forbidden to take off company premises or reveal to third parties. For what to do with these documents I would suggest consulting an attorney, but as for what documents you may want to think about tracking down 'just in case' these would be my suggestions. No guarantees that any of these will be appropriate for use in a court of law.